# Why is the PageRank vector also the eigenvector of the web adjacency matrix?

Tags: graphs, search-algorithms

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank#Damping_factor):

> The PageRank values are the entries of the dominant eigenvector of the
>   modified adjacency matrix. This makes PageRank a particularly elegant
>   metric

Can anyone please elaborate on the connection between the eigenvector and the PR vector? Why are they related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PageRank is the stationary probability (i.e. dominant eigenvector) of the following random walk: with probability 0.85, choose a random outgoing link; with probability 0.15, choose a random web page. The "modified adjacency matrix" that Wikipedia talks about is obtained from the actual adjacency matrix $A$ by computing $0.85 A + 0.15 J$, where $J$ is the all-ones matrix. See [this talk](http://www.kvab.be/downloads/lezingen/bultheel.pdf) (page 13).